# Despite ReadLine() the program closes

Tags: c#, readline, quit

I got a weird problem.
I create an object(inside that object i call readline..) then the program quits despite I called ReadLine() at the end.

Why it doesn't stop? How to make it stops?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Funkcjonalnosc {

    class MainClass {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            new MainMenu();         
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Funkcjonalnosc {
   public class MainMenu {
        int selection;
        public MainMenu() {
            showMenu();
            selection = getSelection();
            Console.WriteLine("Wybrano "+ selection);
            switch (selection) {
                case 1: break; //strojenie
                case 2: break; //pobieranie stroju
            }
        }
        void showMenu() {
            String menu = "1. Nastrój\n2. Dodaj strój";
            Console.WriteLine(menu);
        }

        int getSelection() {//pobiera wybrana opcje z menu{
            try {
                return Console.Read();
            } catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Zly wybor"); getSelection(); }
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: incidentally, I wouldn't consider it good practice to do all that in the *constructor*.

Comment: have you tried .ReadKey(); instead?

Comment: This happens because ur code is crashing before that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN on [`Console.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx):

> The Read method blocks its return while you type input characters; it terminates when you press the Enter key

So if I type, say, <kbd>1</kbd> it doesn't do anything - until I type <kbd>enter</kbd>. When I do that, `Console.Read` returns the <kbd>1</kbd>, but the <kbd>enter</kbd> is still buffered. When you use `Console.ReadLine`, it fetches this buffered <kbd>enter</kbd> so exits immediately. You can see this by typing <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> - the `Read` fetches the <kbd>1</kbd> - and the `ReadLine` fetches the remaining <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>.

To avoid this buffering behavior, you might want to try `Console.ReadKey` instead.